# Regex: Negative Lookbehind + Lookahead in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I'll try to wrap my head around this regex which works on server side.

```
new RegExp(/(?<!:\s*\w*)\w+(?=\s*[,}])/g)
```

it walkes through a string which look like this:

```
{Product{id{$lt:10,$gt:20},title,other,categories{id,name}}}
```

It matches all keys which have no subkeys or values. But this do not work in Javascript because Javascript do not allow Lookbehind Parts of a RegExp. I wonder if there is a workaround in Javascript for this. All what I have read is for Lookbehind only but not for Lookbehind+Lookahead.

You can play around with it here. [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/SXMrPs/1/)

Edit: Some more info: This regexp ist part of an parser which parses a minimalistic query language - a chimera of GraphQL and MondoDB-Queries.

There is function where a string goes in like

```
{Product{id{$lt:10,$gt:20},title,other,categories{id,name}}}
```

and outputs an object. all keys which have no subkeys or values in fact which ends with an ',' or an '}' are replaced with :true. At the end the Output look like this:

```
{
Product: {
    id: { $lt: 10 },
    title: true,
    categories: {
        name: true
    }
}
```

}

I am trying to make it client-side.

Comment: *"...this regex which works on server side..."*: Really? It's strange because few languages accept a variable length lookbehind.

Comment: Only `.NET` and the newer `regex` module in `Python` do support variable lookbehinds as far as I know.

Comment: @Jan Java does too, but not infinite quantifiers.

Comment: Perhaps "should work" I do not know the language, I have only the regular expression and what it does or should do. Nevertheless, how can the described behaviour be done in Javascript? I think that is not possible isn't it?

Comment: as a matter of fact node@9 already supports it (i tried with 9.4)

Comment: to be clearly: It can not be done in plain Browser-ES6-Javascript(?) I have not even an idea for it.

Comment: @Lorfme only Chrome currently supports fixed-length lookbehinds for javascript. Variable-length lookbehinds aren't supported by any browser at the moment.

Comment: You may convert it to a working solution if you add a bit of code. See [**`this JSFiddle`**](https://jsfiddle.net/mvkap4qy/2).

Comment: I imagine you could achieve your goal using capturing/non-capturing group. It isn't perfectly clear what your goal is though. Can you provide some more info, what is your input and expected output? Give some real code snippet please(refrain from `, title,` if you didn't give us `const title=...`)

Comment: @Lorfme what about simply using `[{,]\s*(\w+(?=\s*[,}]))`?

Comment: @ctwheels Chrome V8 supports variable-length lookbehinds according to TC39 draft: [*All regular expression patterns, even unbounded ones, are allowed as part of lookbehind assertions*](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind)

Comment: @sudavid4 - I updated my question with the use case.

Comment: @revo wow, thanks for the correction. All praise Google

Comment: @ctwheels won't work, because it also matches commata and curly brackets.

Comment: @Lorfme check group 1

Comment: @revo - I tried my link above (https://regex101.com/r/SXMrPs/1/) with firefox - does not work and chrome - does work. If i try to compile it with an angular compiler it complains. Very interesting. Is there a cross-browser solution?

Comment: @Lorfme yes, don't use lookbehinds. Use groups.

Comment: No you can't. Why don't you use an approach like [`(?:^|[^:\w\s])\s*(\w+)(?=\s*[,}])`](https://regex101.com/r/1oXgrq/1) and just extract part matched in capturing group one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this solves you problem

```js
const regex = /[{,]\s*\w+(?=[,}])/g
const str = `{Product{id{$lt:10,$gt:20},title,other,categories{id,name}}}`
const result = str.replace(regex, (...a) =>  `${a[0]}:true`)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure the results you're trying to get, but this is your regex
without using the lookbehind assertion.
The whole idea, incase you're interested, is to move the match position
beyond the stuff you don't want to match.

This does that.

```
 (?:                           # -------------
      ( : \s* \w+ )                 # (1), Move past this
   |                              # or,
      ( \w+ )                       # (2), To get to this
 )                             # -------------
 (?= \s* [,}] )                # Common lookahead assertion
```

Generally, you just use the JS callback capability to find out what matched.

```js
var regex = /(?:(:\s*\w+)|(\w+))(?=\s*[,}])/g;
var str = '{Product{id{$lt:10,$gt:20},title,other,categories/{id,name}}}';

var newString = str.replace(
       regex,
       function(match, p1, p2) {  // Callback function
         if (p1) return p1;       // Group 1, return it unchanged
         return p2 + ':true';     // Group 2, modifiy it
       });

console.log(newString);
```

Output

```
{Product{id{$lt:10,$gt:20},title:true,other:true,categories/{id:true,name:true}}}
```